# Python Selenium Clicking All Elements on a Menu

Tags: python, html, selenium, pycharm

I'm trying to click all elements on the navigation menu of python.org. My code runs without any errors, but only the "community" element is clicked. Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/drao/Documents/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.maximize_window()

#finds all elements under mainnav (about, downloads, documentation...)
all_elems = driver.find_elements_by_id('mainnav')
for elem in all_elems:
    if elem.is_displayed():
        elem.click()
```

Here's the html of the webpage

```
<nav id="mainnav" class="python-navigation main-navigation do-not-print" role="navigation">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one element with the ID `mainnav`, so your code is technically working correctly. It grabs the one element and clicks it, then exits. I guess the click falls down to the first clickable element in the DOM.

To get all the clickable tabs you'll need to use a different approach. Here is one that uses the CSS path (this is untested):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/drao/Documents/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.maximize_window()

#finds all elements under mainnav (about, downloads, documentation...)
all_elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('nav#mainnav > ul > li')
for elem in all_elems:
    if elem.is_displayed():
        elem.click()
```

I don't think that ^^^ will actually work though, as the `click()` reloads the page, so all the elements you would have found will have gone stale after the first click.

You could instead take advantage of the `nth-of-type` technique to acquire each element only when needed and click it (tested and working):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    #finds all elements under mainnav (about, downloads, documentation...)
    all_elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('nav#mainnav > ul > li')

    # all_elems is now only useful as a count of all the elems on the screen
    for index, _ in enumerate(all_elems, 1):
        css_path = "nav#mainnav > ul > li:nth-of-type({0})"
        elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_path.format(index))
        if elem.is_displayed():
            elem.click()
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try grabbing all the elements using the following selector:

```
all_elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('nav.python-navigation ul.navigation li')
```

Keep in mind that everytime you click on one of those elements, the entire page reloads, and you might run into StaleElementExceptions